# Hover handlerout check if is hovering something before do something

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave

When I mouseleave I want to change the `li_lancamentos` a.
But, I just want to do that, if when I mouseleave I'm not hovering `li_lancamentos` again.
When I mouseleave from `#li_novo_lancamento` back to `#li_lancamentos` again, `#li_lancamentos` a stills white because of the mouseleave event. I have to put some check on the mouseleave to see if when I mouseleave I`m not hovering`#li_lancamentos` again.

But, how can I do that?

Here is the fiddle with more detailed explanations: http://jsfiddle.net/tehfo/VNmAU/5/

Thanks!

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: The-val, thanks for reading. Here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/tehfo/VNmAU/. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
$('#li_lancamentos').css({"background-color":"white","border":"1px solid white","border-collapse":"collapse","color":"#616161"});
    $('#li_lancamentos a').css({"color":"#616161"});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#li_lancamentos ul a").css("display", "none");
});
$("#menu").hover(function(){
   $("#li_lancamentos ul a").css("display", "block");
});
```

This will make your menu-links appear and disappear when hovering over the menu.
Here is a link to fiddle: jsfiddle.net/VNmAU/11 
Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Almost that Mentohl. Here is the fiddle with some more explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/tehfo/VNmAU/ your  code bugged my current section menu. thanks for the help, if you could see my new fiddle, I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: What should happen when you hover over one of the other menu entries? Should the Lancamentos get a black background? Or should it just stay the way it is?(meaning not disapperaing)

Comment: Okay I updated my fiddle again. Is this somewhat the intended behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/FHq9c/14/
I changed the css too!
The small details like appropriate text-color I think you can fix yourself. :)

Comment: Mentohl almost perfect, now I have a perfect working menu when I'm at the LANÇAMENTOS section. But, when I'm at the RESUMO, for example, Lançamentos is not white... this is what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/tehfo/VNmAU/8/ Thank you again :D.

Comment: I removed this tine: `$('#li_lancamentos a').css({"color":"#616161"});`

Now it's white: http://jsfiddle.net/VNmAU/9/

Comment: OK, it's white, but when you hover the mouse down the menu LANÇAMENTOS (in the <li>'s below) we can't see the LANÇAMENTOS written because it's white... :\\\ Thanks again! :)

Comment: I added another line in the hover-function. http://jsfiddle.net/VNmAU/10/

I am sure now you can manage alone. Just look at what I did. In some cases find other css ids or classes.

I am really glad I could help you, but I don't want to take your fun away, that you will have when you write it alone and learn something doing that. I know you will succeed if you try. ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VNmAU/11/
It did not turn back white... sorry... fixed that. But please, I don't want to write your whole application. I know you can do it yourself. If you have another triky problem just ask another question.

Comment: Man I'm really glad you could help me. I'm very noob so I actually were frozen at it. Now I have another problem but this one I'll try to figure myself again, ok? When in the section LANÇAMENTOS now it stills white. But I'll manage to fix that. Thanks a lot man!!!!!!!!!!!!